# Is $(\int _U f(x)dx)^2\leq \int_U f(x)^2 dx$ true or False?

Tags: calculus

Is the following inequality true or false?

$$\left(\int _U f(x)dx \right)^2\leq \int_U f(x)^2 dx$$

Answer (score 3):

The inequality as such is false.

For instance, consider $f(x)=1$ and $U$ is the interval $[-1,1]$. We then have $\int_U f^2 dx = 2$, whereas $\left( \int_U f dx\right)^2 = 2^2$.

Do you have some restriction on $f$ and/or $U$?